# FBOpenGraphAction runtime error in Swift

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to create a Facebook custom story in my iOS App. I am developing the app in Swift.

```
var graphObject: NSMutableDictionary = FBGraphObject.openGraphObjectForPostWithType(
    "app: type",
    title: "new", 
    image: nil,
    url: nil, 
    description: "description"
)

        (I am getting a runtime error on the following line)
        **var graphAction: FBOpenGraphAction = FBGraphObject.graphObject() as FBOpenGraphAction**


graphAction.setObject(UIImage(named: "default"), forKey: "image")
graphAction.setObject(graphObject, forKey: "break")
```

Am i doing something wrong while declaring the FBOpenGraphAction? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any luck finding a solution to this?

Comment: Not really. I gave up writing the Facebook code in swift and created an objective can class for all my Facebook functions and imported the header files into my swift class.

Comment: Objective C class I meant ** auto correct.

Comment: Ok, I did the same. It's hard to believe how little there is still about FB and swift. Thanks