# How to create an FBOpenGraphAction in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift

With objective-c an FBOpenGraphAction is created like:

```
id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
```

What is the equivalent in Swift?

I would have assumed it is something like this:

```
let action = FBGraphObject.graphObject() as FBOpenGraphAction
```

But this causes a signal at runtime.

See also [FBOpenGraphAction runtime error in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055801/fbopengraphaction-runtime-error-in-swift)

Any ideas are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a known issue and the answer you can find below.

In short, it is not possible to create an action directly in SWIFT, you have to do it with an indirection via Objective-C.

Here the Facebook answer: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/776452979070484/

---

For the case the link does not work or disappears, here a copy of the answer of the FB developer:

The Open Graph API implementation in the iOS SDK v3.x is duck typed and depends on C's weak typing. All casts in Swift are strongly typed. Therefore, because NSMutableDictionary and FBGraphObject do not formally conform to FBOpenGraphObject the Swift cast fails.

You can create Objective-C APIs to perform the cast, e.g. `id<FBOpenGraphObject> FBGraphObjectToFBOpenGraphObject(id<FBGraphObject> o) { return (id<FBOpenGraphObject>)o; }`, as a workaround.

---

I've done this and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is my answer to @jeffjv question from yesterday.

No, I am not trying to convert the meal sample you posted. Anyways, I converted it to Swift for you.

This is the swift code, add it to any swift file:

```
let mealObject = FBGraphObject.openGraphObjectForPostWithType("cooking-app:meal", title: "Lamb Vindaloo", image: "https://example.com/cooking-app/images/Lamb-Vindaloo.png", url: "https://example.com/cooking-app/meal/Lamb-Vindaloo.html", description: "Spicy curry of lamb and potatoes")

let bridge = FacebookBridge()
let cookAction = bridge.graphObject()

cookAction.setObject(mealObject, forKey: "meal")

FBDialogs.presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction(cookAction, actionType: "cooking-app:cook", previewPropertyName: "meal",  handler: { (call: FBAppCall!, result:[NSObject : AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

  if error != nil {
    println("Error: \(error.description)")
  } else {
    println("Success!")
  }

})
```

Then I created a file called FacebookBridge.m as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FBOpenGraphAction.h>

#import "FacebookBridge.h"

@implementation FacebookBridge

- (id<FBOpenGraphAction>) graphObject{
  return (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
}

@end
```

Next I created a file called FacebookBridge.h

```
#ifndef EventCalendar1_FacebookBridge_h
#define EventCalendar1_FacebookBridge_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FacebookBridge : NSObject

- (id<FBOpenGraphAction>) graphObject;

@end

#endif
```

Finally I added the following statement to my bridging-header file which is called YourProject-Bridging-Header.h (YourProject must be the name of your project).

```
#import "FacebookBridge.h"
```

That's it, basically. You must also add some code in your AppDelegate.swift file, but this is documented quite well in the Facebook developer pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a comment but I don't have the rep for it.  I'll delete this later.

@Horowitzathome, can you please include both the swift and objective c interposer you made to get this to work?  I've tried numerous techniques and none work.  I assume you are trying to convert this example, right?

```
id<FBGraphObject> mealObject =
    [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"cooking-app:meal"
                                            title:@"Lamb Vindaloo"
                                            image:@"https://example.com/cooking-app/images/Lamb-Vindaloo.png"
                                              url:@"https://example.com/cooking-app/meal/Lamb-Vindaloo.html"
                                      description:@"Spicy curry of lamb and potatoes"];

id<FBOpenGraphAction> cookAction = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
[cookAction setObject:mealObject forKey:@"meal"];

[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:cookAction
                                      actionType:@"cooking-app:cook"
                             previewPropertyName:@"meal"
                                         handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
    }
}];
```